# PHP loop using HTML tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

Evening all,

The code i am using is as follows :

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 * Template Name: addserverindexoci
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>




<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">



        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<table border="2" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="160%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">  
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Name</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Address</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Port</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Description</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> Status</font</td>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
mysql_select_db("starforg_search") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to Data Base";
$query = "SELECT * FROM ";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();


$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {


        $value = mysql_result($result,$i,"servername");
        $value2 = mysql_result($result,$i,"serveraddress");
        $value3 = mysql_result($result,$i,"portnumber");
        $value4 = mysql_result($result,$i,"description");

ob_start();

if (!$socket = @fsockopen($value2, $value3, $errno, $errstr, 1))
{
  echo "&nbsp;<font color='red'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Offline!</strong></CENTRE></font>";
}
else 
{
 echo "&nbsp;<font color='green'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Online!</strong></CENTRE></font>";  

  fclose($socket);
}
$status = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>


<tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value2; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value3; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value4; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $status; ?></font</td>



<?
$i++;

}

?>  

</div><!-- #primary -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**What i want** 
Now As you can see from the while loop i am trying to display all the data inside of selected fields.

**Whats happening** 
I want to keep looping until all the data is displayed this works, however the data go's to the bottom of the page i am assuming because i am not using end tags for the html e.g < /tr>. the problem is if I enter end tags for the table it will only loop once and display the for set of data in the field the rest of the data will not be in table format.

**The question** 
How can i get the loop to keep displaying all the data in the fields and also show the footer nice and clean,

NOTE: sorry if this is a bit rough i am sick today :(

Comment: Can you get your data into an array or object and use foreach?

Comment: hmm, i was actually looking into that whilst waiting for a responce

Comment: Yeah, If I was doing this, (and I dont money around with wordpress), I would write a little class to pull this data and return an array with the correct results. $results = new Whatever($1,$2,$whatever) foreach($results->gimmeResults() as $value), then just go about your business.  This has the added benefit of removing most of the php from that file above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's wrong with this ?**

```
<table border="2" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="160%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">  
<tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Name</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Address</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Port</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Server Description</font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> Status</font</td>
</tr>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
mysql_select_db("starforg_search") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to Data Base";
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();


$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {


        $value = mysql_result($result,$i,"servername");
        $value2 = mysql_result($result,$i,"serveraddress");
        $value3 = mysql_result($result,$i,"portnumber");
        $value4 = mysql_result($result,$i,"description");

ob_start();

if (!$socket = @fsockopen($value2, $value3, $errno, $errstr, 1))
{
  echo "&nbsp;<font color='red'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Offline!</strong></CENTRE></font>";
}
else 
{
 echo "&nbsp;<font color='green'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Online!</strong></CENTRE></font>";  

  fclose($socket);
}
$status = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>


<tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value2; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value3; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $value4; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $status; ?></font</td>
</tr>


<?
$i++;

}

?>  
</table>
```

and i dont't find **table name** in your query `$query = "SELECT * FROM ";`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that my good man, im sticking to the i'm sick today theme and blaming that, thanks for your time :)

Comment: yer i just removed for posting on the net force of habbit

Comment: happy to help ! get well soon :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $row['servername']; ?></font</td>
     . 
     .
</tr>

<? } ?>
```

you can use like this also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM your table name";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  ob_start();

if (!$socket = @fsockopen( $row['serveraddress'], $row['portnumber'], $errno, $errstr, 1))
{
  echo "&nbsp;<font color='red'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Offline!</strong></CENTRE></font>";
}
else 
{
 echo "&nbsp;<font color='green'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Online!</strong></CENTRE></font>";  

  fclose($socket);
}
$status = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();?>
       <tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $row['servername']; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $row['serveraddress']; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $row['portnumber']; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $row['description']; ?></font</td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $status; ?></font</td>
<?php
 }

mysql_close();




?>
```

Try this one